# npm install always stuck at that exact time

Tags: node.js, npm, truffle

I tried running `$ npm install -g truffle` and `$npm install` but it was constantly freezing at a particular point.

I also tried command `yarn global add truffle` but it was generating an error.

I looked for answers on the internet one of which suggested to run `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and then `npm install`, but now I'm receiving the error:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
yarn command now freezes after a point
```

I'm a beginner, please help.

Comment: Have you tried using sudo?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me many times when I'm using Windows. What I did to make it continue after I felt that it was froze is

1. Click the terminal. Make sure you set the focus on the terminal
2. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is run the command as an administrator.

---

**For Windows (OP's Operating System)**

To run the Command Prompt or PowerShell as an administrator, follow the steps below.

1. Right-click on the Start button (don't open it).
2. Select *Windows PowerShell (Administrator)*, or *Command Prompt (Administrator)* (depending on which one shows for you) in the menu.
3. Allow the operation by entering your password, or clicking *Yes*.

   [image: UAC]

   <sup>Retrieved from a Windows virtual machine.</sup>
4. You can now type in your commands, which will run with administrative privileges.

---

**For macOS/Linux**

To run the command as an administrator, follow the steps below.

1. Open the *Terminal* application.
2. Run the command prefixed with `sudo`.

   ```
   $ sudo
   ```
3. To run all of your commands as `sudo`, run:

   ```
   $ sudo -s
   ```

   You can then type in your commands, which will run under the `sudo` privileges.

**Warning: The `sudo` command can only be run if you have the password for it. When you run a command with `sudo`, it will prompt you once for the password.**